# Categorical variables in recursive feature elimination with random forest

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection

I am trying to use a recursive feature elimination with random forest to find out the optimal features. However, one thing I am confused about is what should I do with categorical variables? Most of time people are doing a one-hot encoder for the categorical variables. But if I do one hot encoder, how can I know which feature is important which is not? Because after doing a one-hot encoder, 1 feature may become multiple features.

My current way is doing a label encoder for all the categorical variables, which means I labeled all the categorical variables as integers. And then using the code

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=101)
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=rfc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(10), scoring='accuracy')
rfecv.fit(X, target)
```

One feature is the 44 different county names, I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.